# Replace NAs within a specific @data column within a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame list

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a large list of 65 SpatialPolygonDataFrames called `map_years`. I need to replace NAs with zeros within a column within the `@data` slot within a SPDF within this list.

I can call on this column by doing this:

```
> map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH
  [1]       NA   642.11       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA     0.00   281.65
```

And I can get a list of which ones are NAs by doing this:

```
> is.na(map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH)
  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But I can't figure out how to replace these NAs. The following do not work :( -

```
[1] map_years[is.na(map_years[["map1950"]]@data$CATCH)] <- 0
[2] map_years[[is.na(map_years[["map1950"]]@data$CATCH)]] <- 0
[3] map_years[["map1950"]]@data[is.na(map_years[["map1950"]]@data$CATCH)] <- 0
```

Here is a screenshot of the structure of this list:

[image: data structure screenshot]

**Edit:** I'm just working with a slightly modified version of the `maptools` dataset `wrld_simpl`, so any examples editing a `@data` column in the `data(wrld_simpl)` dataset works.

Comment: Try `map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH[is.na(map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH)] <- 0`
`

Comment: Yes thank you! I gave up constantly mucking around with the [] @ $ etc. If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH` is a vector, we can use the same technique to replace the values in a vector as follows.

```
map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH[is.na(map_years[["map1951"]]@data$CATCH)] <- 0
```

Furthermore, the above code can be further simplified as the following. The is another way to access a column in the SpatialPolygonDataFrames as accessing the `data` slot is simplified.

```
map_years[["map1951"]]$CATCH[is.na(map_years[["map1951"]]$CATCH)] <- 0
```